# Where to put string checks in Laravel? Controller, model or somewhere else?

Tags: php, laravel

I need to check a string from an input form to check if it's a valid URL. I'm probably going to be using the native PHP function like so:

```
filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Then if the URL is valid I will be making a CURL request to see if I get a 200 response.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

This would be 2 separate functions but my question is where would this code be best placed in the Laravel folder hierarchy?

I suppose it would be *"fine"* in the controller but this feels like business logic to me, however, it doesn't feel correct to new up a Laravel model to just call 2 functions, although I could be over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides multiple ways to validate an incoming data.
There is already a rule for validating an active url [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-active-url).

But as you have multiple requirements, I would go with a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules).

I am not a fan of the curl request being done on the main thread as it will block the request in case the response is delayed, so you can probably use a [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues) for that.